# Edit response object of login in flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am making a small app which requires login functionality. I am using `flask` for making api's and `flask-security` to have login feature.

Login feature is working fine, but I need response object in some customised form.

Right now I am getting response object as:

```
{
  "meta": {
  "code": 200
  },
  "response": {
    "user": {
      "authentication_token": "some token",
      "id": "some id"
    }
  }
}
```

I need output in some customised form which will be:

```
{
  "meta": {
  "code": 200
  },
  "response": {
    "user": {
        "authentication_token": "some token",
        "id": "some id",
        "role": "some role"
    }
  }
}
```

I want role of the user along with response. I saw [flask-security-config](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html) but didn't get any way to do so.

Is there any way, in which I can get this desired behaviour either by changing some config of flask-security or writing some wrapper function on top of this api.

Any useful suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks!